# geth shows "contract creation code storage out of gas" when I deploy contract from remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I created a private network using geth.
And deploy a contract from remix (browser).
It shows following error.

genesis.json is this.

```
{
    "config": {
    "homesteadBlock": 0
    },
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
    "difficulty": "0x4000",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {}
}
```

And I created 2 accounts and run network by this code.

```
geth  --identity "sampleNode" --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "web3,eth,net,personal" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --datadir "~/eth-private-net/" --nodiscover --networkid 10 --unlock 0,1  --verbosity 6
```

And I deployed the contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract SingleNumRegister {
    uint storedData;
    function set(uint x) public{
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() public view returns (uint retVal){
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

After that, it shows error on geth console log.

```
DEBUG[01-27|11:05:50.009] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
```

I got eth by mining and the account has 315 ether on my private network, but it shows same error.

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]);
315000000000000000000
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How much gas do you provide? I tried deploying on remix and it worked just fine.

Comment: I provided 315 ether (= 315000000000000000000wei) before deployint the contract.
Gas limit is 3000000.

Comment: What I meant is how much gas did you provide to the transaction.

Comment: How can I check it?

Answer (score -1):

If you deploy using remix there is a field called `gas limit`. If your gas limit is 3000000 it should be enough, when I deploy your contract on remix it costs much less than that.

Also since you said you deploy on a private blockchain it could have something to do with the gas cost there. Try to deploy in the remix JavascriptVM to see if it works (this works in my case). If it works there try increasing the gas limit when deploying on your private blockchain.

Comment: It works on JavascriptVM on remix.
And I tried to change gas limit from 3000000 to 30000000, 300000000 when deploying from remix, it shows same error message..

Comment: Since it works for JavascriptVM on remix I guess it has something to do with your own blockchain. Try to increase the gas limit on the genesis file and start a new blockchain.

Comment: I increased gas limit as "gasLimit": "0x80000000" but deployment failed.
It shows same error. "contract creation code storage out of gas"